# Check if table exist using SQLite-PCL in a UWP

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp

I'm stuck with how to check if a table already exists.
I have been searching but like many times before I can't find good examples.

The ones I find on SQLite don't work with the PCL version. I can't understand why though, so if anyone has a good site where to go please feel free to add them.

These are the ones I have used:

- http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2015/09/08/Using-SQLite-on-the-Universal-Windows-Platform.aspx
- https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Implement-SQLite-Local-8b13a307#content

This is my code showing how I have tried to check it, but it only checks the path, which always exists. Not a smart solution when I thought about it.

```
private void LikeItButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var sqlpath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "Filmdb.sqlite");

            using (SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn =
                new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), sqlpath))
            {
                if (File.Exists(sqlpath))
                {
                    AdMovieID();
                }
                else
                {
                    conn.CreateTable<MovieID>();
                    AdMovieID();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could execute a query:

```
SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='MovieId';
```

by doing

```
var tableExistsQuery = "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='MovieId';"
var result = conn.ExecuteScalar<string>(tableExistsQuery);
```